# Tenho uma dor de cabeça sobre o evento "abort" ou "onabort" para que ele serve?

Tags: javascript

Já revirei a web inteira busquei ajuda no Google no Youtube já deixei minha duvida em outros sites de pergunta mais nunca acho um exemplo concreto sobre para que ele serve e sempre falam mesma coisa que servem para quando o vídeo for abortado What mais cade o exemplo? cade uma resposta fácil de entender? mais quem poder me ajudar fico grato.

Answer (score 4):

**Abort** é o evento que ocorre quando um recurso (aqui pode se entender como recurso uma imagem, vídeo ou áudio) teve o carregamento interrompido:

[Abort Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/abort)

Para tratar esse evento, o *handler* usado é o **onload**, assim, como o handler para o evento click é **onclick**, e assim por diante:

[onabort event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onabort)

Portanto, para tratar quando o abort ocorre em um elemento, usando o `onabort`, que vai notificar isso.

Exemplos:

```
<video onabort="abortouVideo()">
<img src="" onabort="abortouImagem()">

...

function abortouVideo() { console.log("erro ao carregar video"); }
function abortouImagem() { console.log("erro ao carregar imagem"); }
```

Comment: No caso deste código como eu poderia interromper o vídeo ou a imagem para ele poder executar a menssagem no console?

Comment: mas isso já seria tema de uma outra pergunta, até interessante....
mas de uma forma simples vc não pode "programaticamente" falando fazer isso.... o que pode fazer é talvez mudar o "src" do video durante a carga, isso pode interromper o load, mas precisa testar para confirmar